# Creating Order Programatically Showing Wrong Grand Total

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, programmatically, grand-total, custom-prices

I've successfully created an order programmatically using custom prices for items.
When I view the order, the item is correct, the subtotal is correct, but the Grand Total is double.

Here is my code...

```
    global $StoreId;

    $CustomerId = $_POST['CustomerId'];

    $Quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($StoreId);

    $Customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($CustomerId); // insert customer ID

    // Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
    $Quote->assignCustomer($Customer);

    $address =  $Customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();

    $Quote->getBillingAddress()->importCustomerAddress($address);
    $Quote->getShippingAddress()->importCustomerAddress($address);

    $Quote->setSendCconfirmation(0);

    // Loop to add order. $Item contains the Sku, Qty, Price
    AddItemToQuote($Item, $_product, $Quote);

    try 
    {
        $Quote->collectTotals()->save();
        $Quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
        $Quote->getShippingAddress()
            ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');
        $Quote->getPayment()->setMethod('checkmo');

        // Create Order From Quote
         $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $Quote);
         $service->submitAll();
         $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo '<blockquote>Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "</blockquote>";
    }


function AddItemToQuote($Item, $_product, $Quote)
{
    global $StoreId;

    try 
    {
        $Quote->addProduct($_product, new Varien_Object(array('qty'   => $Item["Qty"])));
        $Quote->save();
        $QuoteItem = $Quote->getItemByProduct($_product);
        $QuoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($Item["Price"]);
        $QuoteItem->setCustomPrice($Item["Price"]);
        $QuoteItem->setIsSuperMode(true);
        $QuoteItem->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "<br>";
        print "Product ID: " . $_product->getId() . "<br>\n";
        print "Product Sku: " . $_product->getSku() . " - " . $_product->getName() . "<hr>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't figured out enough of whats going on behind the scenes to know why, but I did solve the problem by commenting out the following line...

```
    // $Quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
```

.

```
try 
{
    set_time_limit(300);

    $Quote->collectTotals()->save();

    // $Quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();

    // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
    $Quote->getShippingAddress()
        ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');
    $Quote->getPayment()->setMethod('checkmo');
    $QuoteId = $Quote->getId();


    // Create Order From Quote
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $Quote);
    $service->submitAll();
    $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
}
```